# ReactJs: need to change Card into another card onClick

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, react-hooks

here is my goal: There is a "Newuser" button in Login card and it will be clicked, the card will be changed into Register. Login card will be gone. All i have done in material-UI.

my code [in codesand](https://codesandbox.io/s/weathered-cloud-idcp5?file=/src/App.js)

when i click on the button it shows error. if i make this button outside the card i can use if-else condition to show the desired card. but i should keep the button inside the Login form.

while i press the Newuser button, it is saying to use the children array. how can i solve that?
thanx in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have two cards and you want to switch between them - you need someone to handle which of them to show (it will probably be the container of them).

You can use a state to control which card to show, and based on that state to switch between them:

```
const [isLogin, setIsLogin] = useState(true);
const handleRegister = () => {
    setIsLogin(false);
}
```

And inside the login card - when you click on the "register" button just call the `handleRegister` function.

Your login card will need to get the `handleRegister` function in order to call it while the button inside is being pressed:

```
<Login user={user} setUser={setUser} handleRegister={handleRegister} />
```

And you will need to decide which element to show (the login or the register) based on the value of the `isLogin` variable:

```
{isLogin ? <Login user={user} setUser={setUser} handleRegister={handleRegister} /> : <Register />}
```

Here is a working example: https://codesandbox.io/s/happy-moore-8miyc?file=/src/Login.js

Comment: Thanx it’s works. And the explanation is so helpful

Comment: Glad it helped! And an answer without an explanation is really not a good answer. It is more of a cheat for copy&paste, and not for learning.

Answer (score 1):

You could pass a function from your parent to your child as a prop, which will setState a boolean to change the displayed card. This way the button stay in your child.